# Upper and Lower index version of the levi-civita-symbol

Tags: tensors

A few days ago my physics teacher told me about the Levi-Civita-(Symbol/Tensor) and how to use it to write the cross-product. I was interested, So I kept on researching and now I am somewhat stuck. I have seen the identity $\epsilon_{abc} = \epsilon^{abc}$ a couple of times, but I can't find a proof of it anywhere.

I know that lower indices means covariant, upper indices means contravariant and I more or less understand what these concepts are. I tried proving the identity using the Kronecker-Delta.
$$\epsilon_{abc} =\epsilon^{def} \delta_{ad} \delta_{be} \delta_{cf}= \epsilon^{abc}$$
But, not sure if this is correct. could Someone help me out.